# What is the walk out song World Cup 2018?

Tags: football, world-cup, media, fifa

During the FIFA World Cup this year (2018), you can hear a song being played throughout the stadium as the players walk out of the tunnel onto the field. What song is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it's [The White Stripes - 'Seven Nation Army'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0J2QdDbelmY).

Comment: And as far as I remember, it's been played before matches of FIFA World Cup and UEFA Cup for at least ten years already.