# Finland goal song at IIHF WM 2019

Tags: ice-hockey, media

What's the song name which is played after Finland scores goal in IIHF Ice Hockey World Championship 2019 in Slovakia?

Comment: This seemingly [similar question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/18637/what-is-the-walk-out-song-world-cup-2018) was received well. What's the difference?

Answer (score 2):

It's called Peto on Irti by VilleGalle

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svb8hBO52MY